# test return false if upper case or number is present in a text

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

regexp I tried include follows(for upper case). The following returns true

```
self.upperCharCheck = false ; //has to be false by default
var temp ="(?=(.*[^A-Z]))";
self.testUpperCase = new RegExp(temp);
self.upperCharCheck = (self.testUpperCase.test(self.newPassword));
```

I want the self.upperCharCheck to be true if no UpperCase is present and false otherwise if uppercase is present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/[A-Z0-9]/` should be all that's needed to check if a string contains an uppercase letter or a number:

```js
var upperRegex = /[A-Z0-9]/;

console.log(upperRegex.test('should be false'));
console.log(upperRegex.test('should be True'));
console.log(upperRegex.test('should also 0 be true'));

console.log('===');
//This will return false if an uppercase letter or a number is in the string
var upperRegex2 = /^[^A-Z0-9]+$/;

console.log(upperRegex2.test('should be true'));
console.log(upperRegex2.test('should be False'));
console.log(upperRegex2.test('should also 0 be false'));
```

Comment: I want exactly opposite I want                              console.log(upperRegex.test('should be true'));
console.log(upperRegex.test('should be False'));
console.log(upperRegex.test('should also 0 be false'));

Comment: @FalconFlyer I've added the opposite, but you can just simply just negate the call. This: `!upperRegex.test('should be false')` is true. ie. `self.upperCharCheck = (!self.testUpperCase.test(self.newPassword));`

Comment: I wish I could do that. Isnt there any way around the regexp

Comment: @FalconFlyer Check my code snippet. I've added the regex (`upperRegex2`)

Comment: You are awesome can You have a word on how you figured it out that too so quickly.. I mean how does the above work